# How can I compare two string format times?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection called "project" which is having a field expected time and actual time both are in string format

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce7455d77af2d1143f84d49"),
    "project_name" : "p1",    
    "expected" : "0:11:30",    
    "actual" : "7:30:00",    
}
```

How can I compare two string format times using mongodb?
I want to find if actual time is more than expected

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) with [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/index.html) (MongoDB 4.0 or newer) to convert your string values to a number of seconds and then use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) to compare both fields:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            expected: {
                $let: {
                    vars: {
                        parts: {
                            $split: [ "$expected", ":" ]
                        }
                    },
                    in: {
                        $sum: [ 
                            { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$parts", 2 ] } },
                            { $multiply: [ 60, { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$parts", 1 ] } }  ] },
                            { $multiply: [ 3600, { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$parts", 0 ] } }  ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            actual: {
                $let: {
                    vars: {
                        parts: {
                            $split: [ "$actual", ":" ]
                        }
                    },
                    in: {
                        $sum: [ 
                            { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$parts", 2 ] } },
                            { $multiply: [ 60, { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$parts", 1 ] } }  ] },
                            { $multiply: [ 3600, { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$parts", 0 ] } }  ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: { $gt: [ "$expected", "$actual" ] }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert time to any date you want using [**`$dateFromString`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) operator and then can easily use `$lte` `$gte` to perform simple match operations.

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$gt": [
      { "$dateFromString": {
        "dateString": {
          "$concat": ["2018-09-19", "T", "$actual"]
        }
      }},
      { "$dateFromString": {
        "dateString": {
          "$concat": ["2018-09-19", "T", "$expected"]
        }
      }}
    ]
  }
})
```